# Determine a table's primary key using TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, primary-key

I'd like to determine the primary key of a table using TSQL (stored procedure or system table is fine). Is there such a mechanism in SQL Server (2005 or 2008)?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
    JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu 
        ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
WHERE 
    tc.TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' AND 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key'
```

Comment: `ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = ccu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` for multiple schemas

Answer (score 49):

How about

```
sp_pkeys 'TableName'
```

Comment: stellar!   I'm seeing much better performance from this than from the table joins through information_schema

Comment: This would be much handier if it were a table valued function that you could select from

Comment: Can't do anything with the result because it's not a function.

Comment: If you need a table, you can insert the results of a stored procedure into a table. First define the table `declare @PrimaryKey table (TABLE_QUALIFIER nvarchar(100), TABLE_OWNER nvarchar(100), TABLE_NAME nvarchar(100), COLUMN_NAME nvarchar(100), KEY_SEQ int, PK_NAME nvarchar(100))` and then `insert into @PrimaryKey exec sp_pkeys 'TABLE_NAME'`

Answer (score 22):

Here's one based on system tables from SQL 2005 (99% sure it'd work in 2008). This will list all PKs for all user-defined tables, with all columns and some extra fluff that could be removed. Add parameters to pick out a table at a time.

```
SELECT
   schema_name(ta.schema_id)  SchemaName
  ,ta.name  TableName
  ,ind.name
  ,indcol.key_ordinal Ord
  ,col.name  ColumnName
  ,ind.type_desc
  ,ind.fill_factor
 from sys.tables ta
  inner join sys.indexes ind
   on ind.object_id = ta.object_id
  inner join sys.index_columns indcol
   on indcol.object_id = ta.object_id
    and indcol.index_id = ind.index_id
  inner join sys.columns col
   on col.object_id = ta.object_id
    and col.column_id = indcol.column_id
 where ind.is_primary_key = 1
 order by
   ta.name
  ,indcol.key_ordinal
```

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT ccu.COLUMN_NAME, ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS tc
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS ccu
        ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE tc.TABLE_CATALOG = 'Your_Catalog'    -- replace with your catalog
    AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'            -- replace with your schema
    AND tc.TABLE_NAME = 'Your_Table'       -- replace with your table name
    AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Comment: This is _way_ better than the accepted answer, since it provides the table name.

Comment: It is also much better as it has the correct casing on the columns and PRIMARY KEY so it works on a case sensitive server!

Answer (score 6):

```
exec [sys].[sp_primary_keys_rowset] @table_name= 'TableName'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
EXEC sp_Pkeys @tableName
```

Answer (score 3):

You're better off using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`, as you can access the key ordering information (`ORDINAL_POSITION`) which is very important to know.

```
SELECT 
    kcu.*
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu
    INNER JOIN 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
        ON  tc.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME AND 
            tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
ORDER BY 
    tc.TABLE_NAME,
    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't add a comment, not enough rep points, but this is in response to those saying `sp_Pkeys` is not usable. Doesn't have to be a function as mentioned in another comment to an answer.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
  Table_Qualifier varchar(30), 
  Table_Owner varchar(30), 
  Table_Name varchar(50), 
  Column_Name varchar(30), 
  Key_Seq int,
  PK_Name varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbl EXEC sp_Pkeys 'tablename'

select * from @tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is this!

```
select object_id from sys.objects 
where parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'FACounty')
and [type] = N'PK'
```

Comment: This code doesn't return columns that consist primary key, try on composite primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the name of the key you're interested in, following works:

```
-- Assuming you have schema "Example" and the primary key name is "PK_Item"
-- Notice that name of table is irrelevant here but is "Foobar" here
IF (OBJECT_ID('Example.PK_ITEM') IS NULL)
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [Example].Foobar ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Item PRIMARY KEY ...
END
```

Comment: If the OP is trying to find the primary key of a table, why would an answer that relies on knowing the primary key of the table be useful?

Comment: I guess I interpreted the "determine" as "detect if it exists"