# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint error SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here is the code

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions] 
       (DateTime , Dirty, Store_ID, Trans_Type,  Cashier_ID, CustNum, Trans_Amount, Prev_Cust_Balance) 
    SELECT   
       DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, Getdate()), 1, 1001, 'C', 100199,     
       CustNum, -Acct_Balance, Acct_Balance 
    FROM  
       [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] 
    WHERE 
       Acct_Balance <> 0  

UPDATE [cresql].[dbo].[Customer] 
SET Acct_Balance = -500 
WHERE Acct_Balance <> 0  

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

but I am getting this error

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 3
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pkAR_Transactions'. Cannot
>   insert  duplicate key in object 'dbo.AR_Transactions'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

I am not a pro at SQL...any ideas what I am doing wrong

Comment: which field is the primary key?

Comment: Trans_ID is the primary key i think...as i said i dont know SQL...i am a mysql and php developer and i am foriegn to sql server 2008

Comment: As the message clearly says: you're trying to insert a **duplicate value** into whatever is your primary key on that table. Solution: just don't do it! The primary key of a table **must always** be unique - you **cannot** under any circumstances have two identical values for the primary key in two of your rows in the table.

Comment: _Trans_ID_ is the primary key, but I don't see it in your procedure...

Comment: What datatype is `Trans_ID` ?? We're not seeing that anywhere in your statement - is it auto-generated by SQL Server??

Comment: Trans_ID is a bigint and i cant tell if its auto increment...it doesnt look like it and i didnt design this table

Answer (score 2):

By design, your table `[cresql].[dbo].[AR_Transactions]` is supposed to hold only one value for the primary key - in your case, this seems to be a combination of columns that make up this PK.

This is not a SQL issue, but seems to be a design concept.

You should find out what combination of keys is making up your primary key - it may be that the design states that you can insert once and update later on for that combination (although I would not consider this to be good design).

**EDIT**

Since Trans_Id is the PK, and you are not using that column in your insert, it is either being inserted as IDENTITY, as a DEFAULT (brrrrr), or using a TRIGGER.

**IDENTITY:** Check to see if the IDENTITY specification is screwed up. If so, just reset it. Here is how to [How can I reseed an identity column in a T-SQL table variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147210/how-can-i-reseed-an-identity-column-in-a-t-sql-table-variable)

**DEFAULT:** This is an odd choice, and you may have to ask the one who designed the database, read documentation, or just simply figure it out on your own.  In any case, this is a very uncommon choice.

**TRIGGER:** Find the trigger and read through the code to see what it is doing. Here is how to find a list of triggers [What is the most portable way to check whether a trigger exists in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636452/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-whether-a-trigger-exists-in-sql-server)

**Alternate scenario:**

There could be a trigger that inserts into an AUDIT table that may have the problem. Check if the table has any other triggers and see what they do.

Comment: how do i find out what they are

Comment: @Tamer: you decide which field(s) is/are primary key... so you should (must) know when you designed your db...

Comment: @Marco: someone else could have designed the table.

Comment: @Tamer: Use SQL Server Management Studio to connect to the server/database. Then use the query give here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525672/determine-a-tables-primary-key-using-tsql

Comment: i tried this SELECT *     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc         JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name     WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' ............but this didnt give me the AR_Transactions tables primary key

Comment: you should get down voted for this alone. "DEFAULT: Go find whoever designed the table and ask them" More often than not this is not possible.

Comment: @CheapFuneral, you're right.  I will edit my answer.